# Titles given at the workplace

Tags: professionalism, software-industry, career-development, developer, title

I have a simple question. I've never worked for a big company, in my experience, I've been working in a little department with 2 or 3 more developers and that's it, we are no juniors, no seniors, architect, etc, we are just developers.

According to my friends, when you get a job in a big company they give you a title, it doesn't matter if you end your college as a Software Engineer, Computer Science, etc.

I have 2 years programming mobile and web apps for companies and some other apps for the public, and I never went to college, all I learned, was thanks to Google.

So, how should I call my self?

Base on what arguments they give you this titles?

Comment: Whatever title you have been given by your employer, use that. :)

Comment: What was your title when you signed the employment contract?  And what do you need the title for?

Comment: If there is an effective way of describing what you do? Use that. I'm a "consultant", which is a cool title, but needs embelishment to actually communicate what I do.

Comment: Your Employer gives you the Title. It also depends on the Company, so a Manager at Google is considered a higher title than a Manager at a small company that has like 30 employees or so. Some Companys dont give any Titles to avoid hirarchy

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> in my experience, I've been working in a little department with 2 or 3
>   more developers and that's it, we are no juniors, no seniors,
>   architect, etc, we are just developers

Then your current title is "Developer" or something along that line: "Software Developer", "Web Developer" etc. I would generally expect that to be written in your contract.

If you don't work directly for this small department, but instead are a consultant, you can say that: "Software Development Consultant", etc.

> I have 2 years programming mobile and web apps for companies and some
>   other apps for the public

You don't say whether this is with the small department or if some of this was portfolio work or freelance work. If you're wondering how to list it on your CV or describe to people, if this was freelance work, then you can pick whatever is most appropriate. To me, it sounds like something along the lines of "Freelance Mobile & Web Developer".

Comment: +1 for written in the contract, I always just list the title described in my contract.

Answer (score 0):

Junior, Medior, and Senior titles are based on years of experience. Software Architect is not a title - it's a role, just like developer or consultant.

I would say you're on the edge of junior/medior, considering the years of experience you currently have.